# How can I control a slave ESP8266 from a local server and also from another ESP8266?

Tags: esp8266, remote-control, networking

I have a power strip with a ESP8266 which is supposed to turn it on upon command from a OpenHAB server, or to stay on for a predefined time upon command from another ESP8266 (serverless).

The reason is that OpenHAB is used to directly control the strip, while the other master ESP8266 is powered on and off intermittently and periodically sends "refresh" commands to the slave, that will turn off when no more messages are received.

How should I handle the control of the ESP8266? I have never worked with master/slave and I'm confused by the number of available options. For example, MQTT seems a good choice when the server sends the control command, but it requires a software listening and relaying MQTT messages, therefore is not suitable as only control technique because the communication between ESP8266 must not rely on any further network device.

I also thought about simply controlling the slave ESP8266 via webpage and POST/GET commands, since OpenHAB can be set up to use this method as well and that would work also as direct control between ESP8266.

What are my options, their complexity and pros/cons?

Comment: let the esp8266 be a client for OpenHAB and start server for commands from the other esp8266

Comment: @Juraj do you mean using MQTT? I don't understand to which protocol you refer.

Comment: I don't know OpenHAB. Do what it requires. And for the other esp8266 start a server